# Where to store the object with methods in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

What's the right way to store complex objects with methods in Vue? For example, the following object:

```js
const behavior = {
   onClick() {
     console.log('click')
   },
   onDoubleClick() {
     console.log('double click');
   },
   onMounted() {
     console.log('mounted')
   },
   beforeMounted() {
     console.log('before mounted')
   },
   // and so on
}
```

It's needed to pass to my custom component:

```html
<custom-component :behavior="behavior"/>
```

It's need to note: it's not the appropriate approach to pass each method through props, because behavior might change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use mixins for this. Check out [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics).

Comment: I strongly disagree. For example, I can have the multiple behaviors for different components. Mixins will conflict with each other.